# SQL: Check if a row exists for each condition

Tags: sql

I'm not able to find a correct SQL query for my needs.
I have a table like this:

```
first_id | second_id | value
1          1           valueABC
1          2           valueLoL
2          1           valueBlaBla
2          2           valueLoL
```

Now I would like to select the first_ids where they have at least one row for **EACH** condition:

```
second_id = 1 and value = 'valueABC'
AND
second_id = 2 and value = 'valueLoL'
```

I already tried this, but the query is not correct:

```
select distinct first_id from myTable where (second_id = 1 and value = 'valueABC')
and (second_id = 2 and value = 'valueLoL') group by first_id having count(first_id) = 2
```

So in my example, first_id = 1 should be selected, as we have a row for each condition.

Can you help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't that be an OR rather than an AND? I don't think you can have valueABC and valueLOL on the same record.

Comment: No, I would like to select the first_ids where they have at least one row for EACH condition. Each condition should be filled. I don't know if it's clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select first_id from
(select first_id, 
sum(case when second_id = 1 and value = 'valueABC' then 1 else 0 end) as nbCond1,
sum(case when second_id = 2 and value = 'valueLoL' then 1 else 0 end) as nbCond2
from myTable
group by first_id) t
where nbCond1 > 0 and nbCond2 > 0;
```

Basically grouping by `first_id` and counting how many times the two conditions appear in a row for each `first_id`, then only selecting `first_id`s that have the number of occurences of both conditions > 0.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2530462c095fc743ad767e6fc37a560a)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like the following:

```
select first_id
from t
group by first_id
having 
    Max(case when second_id = 1 and value = 'valueABC' then 1 end) is not null and 
    Max(case when second_id = 2 and value = 'valueLoL' then 1 end) is not null;
```